# The word for not a word

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

A few years ago I came across a distinct word used to reference non-words. Most people's guesses are intuitive though unfortunately aren't correct as it's a very distinct word. We're not talking about normal slang or utterances by a disillusioned person; more along the lines of people making things up on the spot that have no merit to exist.

Origins of these non-words could be from corporate pseudo-"culture" or non-professional advertising and marketing people. Slang would be relatively considered classy because there is some form of legitimacy to that word's existence versus if I made up the non-word 'qabefter' because I wanted to make a word that rhymed with something and had a certain meaning, not a legitimate word.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for something like 'neologism' but with a negative connotation?

Comment: @Silenus I don't want to give any real world examples due to hypersensitivity though neologism doesn't fit the bill (though is itself similar in complexity to the word I came across) and *yes*, the word I'm looking for certainly has a negative connotation.

Comment: [*Nonce word*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word) (or *occasionalism*) ?

Comment: FYI: A word beginning with "qa" will suggest the Qt programming language to a small segment of programmers, and nonsense words beginning with "q" will suggest several different programming environments.

Comment: @ermanen A nonce-word has a legitimate use as either the lack of immediate knowledge of the proper word or enough insight to know English does not yet have an appropriate word.

Comment: @HotLicks Programmers tend to be on a much higher level of intelligence than the people who would create these useless meaningless words. There may be a hundred legitimately different ways to brand the same solution if each of those solutions are each tailored to specific scenarios with differing contexts...so no, that context you mentioned does not apply to the word I'm searching for.

Comment: @John: A *nonce word* is a word coined for a particular occasion. The definition is along the line of what you said: "people making things up on the spot that have no merit to exist."

Comment: Other terms that may fit: [*nonsense word*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonsense_word) and *stunt word*.

Comment: @John An "aberration;" an "aberrant" word? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aberration

Comment: Encountered 'pseudoword' and 'logatome' while googling 'nonce-word' and 'occassionalism'. Does you have any intuition about what the word begins with? Very often a person's first guess is correct and it might help in the search (or it might lead us astray).

Comment: Just saying that if you create a nonsense word somewhere adjacent to the programming universe be prepared for it to be interpreted differently.

Answer (score 3):

**Nonword** is in Merriam Webster's Collegiate Dictionary tenth edition, which was first published in 1993. More readily accessible is the American Heritage Dictionary 5th edition and the Random House Webster Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary at [The Free Dictionary by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nonword).

The A.H.D's. definition is:

> A sequence of letters or sounds that is not accepted as a word by speakers of a specific language, sometimes used in psychological or linguistic experiments.

**The Usage Addendum:** Nothing about the signification in and of is good or bad.

As noted by the definition here, this word is used in academic contexts where researchers are supposed to remain as free from bias as possible. Although nobody can be completely free from bias, experiments generally have guidelines, such as double blind testing and control groups to minimize its effects. Using anything that doesn't have a neutral register would likely be met with disapproval. I have no reason to imagine that such is the case in [Nonword Pronunciation and Models of Word Recognition](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7844510) which seems to look at them with intrigue. The study *[Preschool Speech Articulation And Nonword Repetition Abilities May Help Predict Eventual Recovery Or Persistence Of Stuttering](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25173455)* by Spencer C. & Weber-Fox C. even seems to have a positive outlook for therapeutic use against stuttering.

Sometimes nonwords are met with much approval, especially in the field of entertainment. Consider the following exemplary quote from Introducing Psycholinguistics by Paul Warren, page 164:

> Scrambled prose is neither syntactical nor semantically well-formed but consists of real words (10.20).
>
> Jabberwocky named after the poem in Lewis Carrol's *through the looking glass*, is syntactically well-formed, but has nonwords in the place of most or all of the content words and so has little meaning, such as *The waggy glim vorpily thazzes a veeg.*

"Jabberwocky" with nonwords seems to be preferable to Scrambled Prose with "real" ones by this description. Moreover, the poem it references is met with much approbation for its convincingly fluent use of

Now it is true "little meaning" is not a very complimentary statement but it is an inescapably inherent quality of the concept meant to be conveyed, since this is the primary (albeit not only) difference between what a [word](https://wordnik.com/words/word) is and is not:

> A sound, or combination of sounds, used in any language as the sign of a conception, or of a conception together with its grammatical relations; the smallest bit of human language forming a grammatical part of speech; a vocable; a term.
>
> ---
>
> The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia

Yes, the word is used in critical contexts but it is the context which imparts negativity onto the word, rather than this word selection. Moreover such users of nonword is at issue with the fact that a nonword either fails to serve a word's purpose or if it is proposed as a neoglism, somehow fails to serve it well enough.

Moreover, I suspect that such critics are more likely to say it is "not a real word" or even a "fake word" to highlight the lack of genuineness these words have (which isn't to say everybody who uses those phrases means them critically either), whereas nonword simply negates the root.

Comment: Yes, but OP mentions this. Which should attract a downvote for lack of research, and/or a comment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In this case I think it's understandable for a few reasons. One is that the word is often used in negative contexts (I don't believe the negativity is inherent to the word. I should add some note to that effect.) Another is that hyphenated words, like what he used really don't show up in searches. Another is that only Am. English Dictionaries seem to list it (Collins isn't listed for instance). Finally, it seems to be rather recently accepted, since the 4th edition of Am. heritage doesn't accept it, hence why I mentioned the date for the M.-W. 10th. It's somewhat hard to find.

Comment: A Google search for ' "non-word" meaning' gives M-W, ODO, dictionary.reference.com, yourdictionary.com, dictionary.reverso.net (and a language site) returns (including the solid and hyphenated forms) on the first page, at my space-time coordinates.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OP _uses_ it as opposed to mentioning it.

Comment: @Mitch He uses 'non-words' to mean what the dictionaries mean by 'non-words' (though perhaps he doesn't realise this). This qualifies as mentioning the word. Essentially he asks 'What is a word for non-words?'

Comment: The OED lists "***non-word*** as '*a thing that is not a word; spec. an unrecorded or hitherto unused word; a word which has (or is regarded as having) no accepted meaning*'.  Citations (starting 1893, with spellings 'non-word' and 'nonword') in following comment.

Comment: OED *non-word* citations - 1893   Atlantic Monthly Aug. 187/1   *Thus the sages approach Brahman by means of his manifestation, his created works; ‘by the word is the non-word revealed*’.
1956   Amer. Lit. 28 89   *A group of nonwords and senseless repetitions for which Melville should not be held responsible*.
1970   Gainesville (Florida) Sun 8 Jan.   *The School Board's petition to the Supreme Court contained an error, the non-word ‘predominately’*.
1992   Eng. Today Oct. 41/1   *My high-school English teacher was fond of slashing users of the non-word ‘irregardless’*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I agree that the OP question is tautologous.  Very often in English there is a 'common' word and a 'posher' word for the same thing.  I initially interpreted the OP as wanting a 'posher' word than 'non-word'.   'Nixinym' does fit the bill for a posh version :-).

Comment: I'm happier with AHDEL's wider definition of _nonword_  'A[ny] sequence of letters or sounds that is not accepted as a word by speakers of a specific language, sometimes used in psychological or linguistic experiments.' than say that given at Wikipedia. However 'not accepted as a word by speakers of a specific language' is imprecise, as native speakers are rarely in total agreement as to word-status.

Answer (score 1):

The word for not a word is ***nixinyms***. This is a portmanteau of *nix* and *nym*.

- *Nix* means *no*.
- *Nym* literally means name, from the Greek *onoma* meaning *name* or *word*.

Other words for words are also *-nyms*, such as *acronyms, antonyms, synonyms, toponyms, autonyms, pseudonyms* and so on.

Comment: Is 'nixinym' a nixinym?

Comment: @Silenus *nixinym* is a nixinym but if we use it it becomes an *isanym* (from "is a" + nym=word).

Comment: Well it's not in the OED, but I like it!

Comment: @Dan: Correction: it's not *yet* in the OED :)

Comment: I like it though it doesn't infer any sense of non-nonsensical or of being obscene. Going to wait it through for a bit and see.

Comment: @John: Of course it doesn't infer any sense of being sensical or obscene; why should it? You never mentioned that in your question.

Comment: Nixinym does not (as per Google data) come anywhere near fulfilling the 'reasonably commonly used / understood' criterion demanded by 'word'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Which authority says a word demands 'reasonably commonly used / understood'? *Nixicon* meets the criterion of ***"a single distinct meaningful element of speech or writing, used with others (or sometimes alone) to form a sentence and typically shown with a space on either side when written or printed."***

Comment: The main difficulty I see with this suggestion's possible adoption is that it mixes etyma from different languages (nix is german). I'm personally apathetic to that but other people who use the -nym words might care. All of the presently accepted -nym words I know of in English, like hypernym, metonym, acronym, synonym and antonym are *strictly* Greek.  [Alphadictionary's methodology for their Corrected List of Phobias](http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/phobia_corrections.html) shows that they should oppose it. Oxinym would probably be more readily accepted since oxi is Greek for no.

Comment: We've had this discussion here time after time. _BX%uUu$4e_ may mean something to a group of spies, but it's senseless to say it is a 'word' in any meaningful general sense. They may adapt the meaning of 'word' for their purposes, in their jargon, of course, but they are not entitled to foist their sense on the general public.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicon) mentions the 'having gained widespread usage' constraint:  'Linguistic theories generally regard human languages as consisting of two parts: a lexicon, essentially a catalogue of a language's words (its wordstock)....  Lexicalization is the process in which new [hitherto candidate] words, having gained widespread usage, enter the lexicon.' And 'nixinym' hasn't.

Comment: The Wiki's. not very authoritative since anybody can abuse it. Anyway,  Noah Webster's entries for [word](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2331471) and [language](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2260575) in The American Dictionary of the English Language suggest that a word can be between just any two people but what constitutes a word in a language such as the English one is a matter of both group consensus and tradition. Hime's a word for princess that's understood by a considerable number of English speakers due to the influence of Anime, yet it's still considered Japanese for these reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The English language has no such concept. Simply making something up will become canon, if it becomes ubiquitous.

Comment: The concept of the number/word 'zero' did not originally exist for some time too.

Comment: Concepts are not language. You can express the concept of there being no word for a concept by saying 'there is no word for that concept'. There may very well be no _single_ word for the concept, which would be a limitation of English.